# Does QGIS have the equivalent of ArcGIS's Layer (*.LYR) file?

Tags: qgis, qgis-2, layer-file

Using ArcMap, it is possible to add a dataset (eg a shapefile) to the map, and configure the layer's properties (such as the symbology, table joins, switching some attributes off in the Identify results, etc).

This layer can then be saved as a Layer file:

[image]

The resulting *.lyr file references the data source (the shapefile) and all of the properties which have been configured for that layer. This makes it easy to add this same layer to multiple map documents, inheriting all of the properties which have been set.

Is there an equivalent in QGIS?

Answer (score 38, accepted):

It does [now](https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/commit/3c3872176c2583feb587ba4c708563c6c957441a) :)

Only in the dev version but something like this could be added in an older release using a plugin.  If I get some time I might just do that.

[image]

[image]

A QGIS Layer Definition file will have the `*.qlr` extension and is a XML dump of the `maplayer` node for the project.

The start of the file will look like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE qgis-layer-definition>
<maplayer minimumScale="-4.65661e-10" maximumScale="1e+08" simplifyDrawingHints="1" minLabelScale="0" maxLabelScale="1e+08" simplifyDrawingTol="1" geometry="Polygon" simplifyMaxScale="1" type="vector" hasScaleBasedVisibilityFlag="0" simplifyLocal="1" scaleBasedLabelVisibilityFlag="0">
  <datasource>F:/gis_data/cadastre.shp</datasource>
  <title></title>
  <abstract></abstract>
  <keywordList>
    <value></value>
  </keywordList>
  <layername>cadastre</layername>
  ... {style, etc}
</maplayer
```

**QGIS 2.8 Update**

As of 2.8 QLR files now support many layers as well as groups.  Right click on a group in the legend to save it out to a QLR file everything under the group will be saved to the QLR file.

Comment: now that's what I call customer service

Comment: This will work for vector and raster, including WMS, etc.  It doesn't work with a OpenLayers layer for example.

Comment: Will it work for database stored data?  PostGIS, Spatialite, etc?

Comment: Yes everything.

Comment: A minor quibble, but should the wording be "Save layer definition file" rather than "Save as"?

Comment: No because `Save As..` is a create new file operation, `Save` is overwrite a current you have open. We never keep a `.qlr` file open so there is no reference.

Comment: Customer service or insider trading...  ; /

Comment: Customer service

Comment: This is great...I was looking for this a few months back.

Answer (score 9):

Not exactly.  You can save your symbology to SLD file or qgis layer style file (.qml).  Like .lyr file these files save your symbology options, however, they do not point to the data itself.  You have to re-add the layers then apply the style or SLD file.  The SLD file only stores symbology, .qml files store symbology, labeling options, even edit widgets for your fields.