# How to publish a single (standardized) QGIS symbology which relates to different datasets of same schema?

Tags: qgis, symbology, style, font, publishing

Given a specific (locally extended/stored) symbology and styling in QGIS which refers to several different shapefiles or tables (GeoPackage/Spatialite), how can I easily move or share this with another QGIS desktop user?

Currently, the QGIS symbology is managed in the project file (`.qgs`) plus there are configuration settings like symbology and font paths. So the symbology is "hard wired" to the dataset and to local symbologies and fonts.

What I want is to publish a single "generic/template" symbology (i.e. signature/symbol settings) with a mapping to exchangeable datasets names - all in paths relative to the symbology (but without the dataset). ArcGIS knows a similar thing they call `.MDX` and "Map Package".

An example would be a topographic map style from an authority ("mytopostyle" with `.qgs`, symbole/text fonts, etc.) referring to `mydata`, which is then published and applied to different, separate regions containing all the same data schema (files `mydata_region_A.sqlite`, `mydata_region_B.sqlite` , ...).

Any hints?

Comment: This might be a duplicate of http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/88834/ I'm somewhat unclear on what you're after. A map package in ArcGIS contains *everything* - the symbology *and* the data. If you just want symbology you can share, in ArcGIS that's a layer (lyr) file. And in QGIS it's covered at the above link. http://giswiki.hsr.ch/QGIS_All-in-one_Project_Plugin talks about the equivalent to a map package (not sure if there are other methods). Fonts may not be included - some can't be redistributed and it depends on the software if a font is just referenced or embedded in an output.

Comment: To me, it seems like the key issue here are SVG and font paths. I'm not sure there is a good solution though ...

Comment: Chris: To rephrase my question: It's about to how to best setup a QGIS project file .qgs and *all* files needed for the symbology including symbols (e.g. .svg) and fonts (without the data). The All-in-one Project Plugin (which comes from my lab) covers another use case where one wants to move one single whole project to another computer. This use case is about a symbology like a "template" which renders datasets of same schema.

Comment: underdark: Exactly - but not only the paths also the SVG and fonts themselves which need to be "installed" in a user friendly way. AFAIK ArcGIS has a similar problem at least for adjusting paths to the data for every layer - so QGIS could take a lead here :-)

Answer (score 1):

Chris and underdark: It seems that there's no answer out-of-the-box. But your comments brought up to me a possible partial solution.

One could re-use the "All-in-one Project" (AIOP) file package and plugin!

As a publisher:

1. First one would setup everything (symbology, symbols/fonts and a
   demo dataset).
2. Then one could (somehow) remove the dataset,
3. and deliver/publish this truncated AIOP file.

As a consumer:

1. After downlading the AIOP file
2. the plugin would install the symbols/fonts...
3. ... and during re-opening, QGIS would ask for the data.

I still have to think over this solution and probably have to enhance the AIOP plugin (still experimental).