# Style file with QGIS

Tags: qgis, maps

I created a very good symbol layout for a current map.  I will be creating similar maps just different regions and want to keep the symbols and markers that way they are.  The new data will have same attributes.  I know with ArcMap I could create just a layer file and the symbols and line colors would be saved.  In QGIS how do I do this.  I have looked on the board and saw you can save just one to a .qml file.  I want to save everything to the same file.  Is that possible even.  I tried grouping all my symbols together, but could not get it to save to a .qml.

Comment: Have you looked at [Does QGIS have the equivalent of ArcGIS's Layer (*.LYR) file?](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/88834/does-qgis-have-the-equivalent-of-arcgiss-layer-lyr-file)

Comment: So you want to save the style of the map or all the styles into a single file?

Comment: You'll likely have to save 'layer definition files' for each layer you're trying to save...

Answer (score 2):

If you are creating similar maps for different regions, you could create an atlas in the print composer, and use presets to control which layers are shown for each region, if these will need to change. You can then very quickly copy & paste styles between your styled layers and the new additions. Even if you need to export the map for each region as an individual file rather than all together as one atlas (so you can change presets for each region) this should be an efficient method.