# How to export shapefile with colours from QGIS

Tags: qgis, color

I want to export shapefiles from QGIS. The shapefiles have been colored by category, but when i export them, the exported files does not have colors, but only the lines that divide the categories. I want to mantain the colors while exporting instead.

Comment: A feature's geometry and attribute table and the feature's symbology are usually stored as a separate files with a GIS. [This](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/180300/style-file-with-qgis) and [this](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/88834/does-qgis-have-the-equivalent-of-arcgiss-layer-lyr-file) may provide some leads.