# "save as" a vector layer with new source files but retain formatting

Tags: qgis, symbology

I often need to duplicate a vector layer, creating new data source (shapefile) files so that I can then delete some features in the duplicate layer without deleting them in the original data. I need to retain all of the formatting settings, etc. as I do this. I have been using "save as" (after right-clicking on the layer to be duplicated), but then need to go through and format the symbol, labels, etc.. Is it possible to do this while retaining the formatting settings?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Together with saving the new shapefile, you can also save the style (**Layer Properties->Style** tab then click the **Style** button). If you save the style using the name of the new, duplicated layer, it will be applied automatically when you next open the duplicate shapefile.

Comment: Good to note that this saves a layername.qml file which stores the style, QGIS automatically applies any qml files that have the same name as the shapefile.

Answer (score 7):

Most (styling) settings can easily be copied from an existing layer to e.g. duplicates, which seems the best option here. Works quite like *copy-paste*, in the layer window

- *right-click* the (style) source layer -> *styles* -> *copy style*
- *right-click* the target layer(s) -> *styles* -> *paste style*

There are other options involving different layer- or symbology definition files, check both answers for [this](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/88834/does-qgis-have-the-equivalent-of-arcgiss-layer-lyr-file) question for a few examples (it´s an old post but covers two common other options).